# VBA Call Function with Hyperlink and Open Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, function, hyperlink

I set up a hyperlink formula in excel:

```
=HYPERLINK("#NotifyReceivers()";"Notify")
```

and the NotifyReceivers Function in VBA:

```
Public Function NotifyReceivers()

Dim wb_dash As Workbook
Dim DashBoardFolder As String, report_name As String, wb_dash_name As String, emailGrant As String, report_easy As String
Dim c_report As Integer, r_report As Integer, c_email As Integer
Dim objOutlook As Object

Set NotifyReceivers = Selection

DashBoardFolder = "C:\some\file\path"

c_report = FindString_ReturnColumn(ThisWorkbook.Name, DashMngrLoadReportsSheetName, DashMngrReportName) ' this is a custom function I use to find the column number of the first cell where the DashMngrReportName string is found (given in input the Workbook Name, the Worksheet and the string I want to find)
r_report = Selection.Row
report_name = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DashMngrLoadReportsSheetName).Cells(r_report, c_report).Value
emailGrant = ""

wb_dash_name = FindFileName(DashBoardFolder, ".xlsm", DashBoard_Identifier) ' this is a custom function that returns the name of a file given the location, the file extension and a substring that identifies the file name
Set wb_dash = Workbooks.Open(DashBoardFolder & "\" & wb_dash_name, , True)

With wb_dash
    r_report = FindString_ReturnRow(.Name, DashTechnicalSheetName, report_name) ' this is a custom function I use to find the row number of the first cell where the report_name string is found (given in input the Workbook Name, the Worksheet and the string I want to find)
    c_report = FindString_ReturnColumn(.Name, DashTechnicalSheetName, DashReportExactName)
    report_name = .Worksheets(DashTechnicalSheetName).Cells(r_report, c_report).Value
    c_report = FindString_ReturnColumn(.Name, DashTechnicalSheetName, DashReportSempli)
    report_easy = .Worksheets(DashTechnicalSheetName).Cells(r_report, c_report).Value
    
    c_report = FindString_ReturnColumn(.Name, DashAccessRightsSheetName, report_name)
    c_email = FindString_ReturnColumn(.Name, DashAccessRightsSheetName, DashAccessRightsEmailCol)
    i = 1
    Do While Not IsEmpty(.Worksheets(DashAccessRightsSheetName).Cells(i, c_report))
        If .Worksheets(DashAccessRightsSheetName).Cells(i, c_report).Value = DashAccessRightsEnabled Then
            emailGrant = emailGrant & "; " & .Worksheets(DashAccessRightsSheetName).Cells(i, c_email).Value
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    emailGrant = Right(emailGrant, Len(emailGrant) - 2)
End With
wb_dash.Close Savechanges:=False

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objEmail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "sender@email.com"
    .bcc = emailGrant
    .cc = "sender@email.com"
    .Subject = "REPORT NOT AVAILABLE | Information on today's reporting"
    .Body = "Hello, the report was not made available today. Best Regards."
    .Display
    .Save
End With

Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Function
```

This is part of a broader project where I declared several public constants where I store Sheets' names, column names, etc.

The problem is that when I run the function by clicking directly on the hyperlink I get the "Reference isn't valid" error, because, I've tested it, the wb_dash file doesn't open.
Instead, when I select a cell where the Hyperlink formula is stored and then run the code from the VBA interface (by pressing the "F5" key), the code works perfectly.

Any ideas on this behaviour? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: There are some limits on what a method called from a hyperlink can do, and I'm not sure they're documented as such but the limits appear to be similar to those imposed on functions called as UDF's: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel-f2f0ce5d-8ea5-6ce7-fddc-79d36192b7a1#:~:text=A%20user%2Ddefined%20function%20called,add%20sheets%20to%20a%20workbook.  You could consider using regular hyperlinks instead of the HYPERLINK() worksheet function, and have the worksheet's `FollowHyperlink` event call your code.